# Precision on two different approximations

Tags: taylor-expansion

Theoretically, how should I compare the precisions of the following two approximations?

$f(x_2) = f(x_1) + (x_2-x_1)\times df(x_1)$

$f(x_2) = f(x_1) + (x_2-x_1)\times\frac{[df(x_1)+df(x_2)]}{2}$

where $df$ is the first-order derivative of $f$.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @Spectre thank you

Comment: You are most welcome :)

Comment: There is no comparison that will always be true, but if the second derivative of $f$ is bounded tightly enough, *and you drop the absolute value* from the second formula, then it will be superior to the first. With the absolute value, it will be really crappy when $df < 0$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair ,that's may help thank you.